# How to create shortcut to insert specific special character

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I'm using some special characters like mathematical symbols in different programs like Mail or Adobe Illustrator. Of course I can open the Symbols Table, search for the needed symbol and copy&paste it. Is there a way to define a shortcut to insert a specific special character?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities are through creating a modified keyboard layout (which can be done manually, but is made much simpler using a program like [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)) or through a shortcut program like [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/)

I use TextExpander, myself, so that c== is a shortcut on my system for ⌘, o== for ⌥, and several others, in part because I do not want to lose the symbols already mapped to the option (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) key combinations on my keyboard.

On the other hand, remapping the <kbd>⌥</kbd> keys to symbols different than the ones they are original configured for can be helpful and convenient for some people also, which is where Ukulele shines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in Automator and Services. Look at [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/tilde-with-hiragana-input/35334#35334) to the similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get *very* fast access to the symbols via the widget **[CharacterPal](http://www.tacowidgets.com/widgets/)**.

Click on the needed icon in order to paste to the clipboard.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean copy to the clipboard?

Comment: And which icon?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "\UF704" = { // F1
        "a" = (insertText:, "∀");
        "2" = (insertText:, "²");
    };
    "~a" = (insertText:, "∀");
}
```

After restarting applications, pressing <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd> should insert "∀".

Answer (score -1):

You may create an AppleScript that insert your character.

Then, it is possible to have this script in the Scripts menu at the right.

Then I think that, in the menu, the script can have a keyboard command.

Then you are done!