# Switch key mapping for £ and # for Macbook with British keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I recently replaced my 2015 Macbook Air with a 2020 one (both British keyboards). On the new keyboard `shift + 3` = £ and `option + 3` = #. Previously the roles of these keys were reversed (`shift + 3` = # and `option + 3` = £). I use the # symbol much more often, so how can I change the key mapping back to what I am used to?

Comment: What Language do you have set in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input Sources? British 'standard' is to have £ on shift/3, US is on opt/3.

Comment: My language is set to British. So maybe my previous laptop was set to US. I don't want to change the language (I think it affects other keys) so maybe I will have to get used to this key.

Comment: What you have is the default standard for a UK keyboard. You can experiment by adding other languages to the input settings. Holding various shift/opt keys will show you the changes 'live' without having to commit…. or you can have both & swap between

Comment: There is no need to change your Language & Region setting, it has nothing to do with the keyboard mapping, and the keyboard mapping has nothing to do with spellcheck.

Comment: Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49565/how-can-i-expand-the-number-of-special-characters-i-can-type-using-my-keyboard and https://superuser.com/questions/463456/how-to-configure-keyboard-shortcuts-for-special-characters-on-os-x? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Just change your Input Source to US or ABC instead of British.  Nothing else of importance will be affected.

Comment: Such a simple solution, this has changed my life